# Center state through providers in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement a "tool module" for a 3D view that consists basically of buttons, which will trigger actions and settings, which will set up these actions. Settings and buttons are located in different sides of the view, so they cannot be under the same DOM element.

What I'm trying to sort out is how to implement a declarative way to setup these tools, so that something like this is possible:

```
<Tools>
  <Tool name="Zoom out">
    <Trigger> - </Trigger>
  </Tool>
  <Tool name="Slice model">
      <Trigger> - </Trigger>
      <Settings><Slider/></Settings>
  </Tool>
</Tools>
```

This would allow me to keep state inside a  component:

```
const SliceModelTool = () => {
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState<boolean>(false);
 
  handleChange = (value : number) => {
    //do stuff
  }


  return (
    <Tool name="Slice model">
      <Trigger onClick(() => setActive((prev) => !prev)> - </Trigger>
      {
         isActive && 
         <Settings><Slider onChange={handleChange}/></Settings>
      }
    </Tool>
  )

}
```

This would require a sort of DOM manipulation that I'm not sure is possible.

I've tried to use hooks in order to setup the components inside the a module provider which would keep tool state, bun this doesn't seem right considering how React works.

Comment: You setup a context at the root element that contains all your tools, and each tool can grab the values and state setters each tool needs from that. So _"use hooks in order to setup the components inside the a module provider which would keep tool state"_ is exactly how React works. What about that approach didn't work for you?